# What goes into the scope of a contructor defined outside the class?

Tags: c++

I am studying some advance c++ code and I am struggling to understand what the author was trying to define in the scope of the constructor he defines outside the class:

The code looks something like this:

```
class myclass(){} // defined somewhere else.
    
myclass::myclass(const char *x, const char *y, const char *z): 
    variable_A(x), variable_B(y), variable_C(z)
    {
      runsomefunction();
      runanotherfunction();
    }
```

The runsomefunction is not defined in the class.

Essentially what I need to know is what can I do in the scope (i.e. in the curly braces after the constructor initialisers) of a constructor formed in this manner. Or rather, what do people do in those braces.

Note that: the definition of the cluster in this example is incomplete. The original code is quite lengthy and my question is just specific to the scope of the constructor that looks like this.

Comment: `runsomefunction();` is not a definition. Its a function call. The function must be defined somewhere else

Comment: There's something wrong with the code in the question. `variable_A`, `variable_B`, and `variable_C` are not members of the class, but they're being initialized in the initializer list.

Comment: There's nothing special about writing the definition of a constructor in the class or outside of the class. The constructor (and any other member function) can use the names of any members of the class. It can also use the names of things that aren't members of the class if those names have been declared before they are used.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Technically not necessarily. Depends on what `runsomefunction` is. Names can be deceiving :)

Comment: @eerorika if macros are in, it could even be a definition ;). Of course you are right, wrongly assuming the "obvious" can be dangerous.

Comment: @PeteBecker how do you know that `variable_A`, ... , `variable_C` are not members of the class?

Comment: @skpro19 The class definition is shown. It has no members.

Comment: @PeteBecker by class definition, are you referring to `class myclass(){}` ?

Comment: @skpro19 -- oops, that's not a class definition. It's not valid. Let me suggest that instead of sniping at comments that you make that point directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is ill-formed because the class definition doesn't declare the constructor that is defined, nor the sub objects that the constructor initialises.

> what the author was trying to define

The author has defined a class, and a constructor.

> Essentially what I need to know is what can I do in the scope (i.e. in the curly braces after the constructor initialisers)

Those curly braces are a block statement. You can do things there that you could do in any block statements, and furthermore things that you can do in member functions. Constructor is a (special) member function.

Here are some more examples of block statements:

```
void example_function()
{                  // <-- beginning of a block statement
    if (something) // if-statement is something that
                   //     can be only within block statements
    {              // <-- beginning of a block statement
                   // An if-statement doesn't necessarily
                   //     contain a block statement, but
                   //     it is quite typical.
    }
}
```

It is quite rare to need to do anything in the block statement of a constructor, but when you need to, it's there for you to do what you need.